# Are there any effects that improve the accuracy of the Vehicle Machine Gun?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 2, the machine gun on the vehicle has a pretty wide spray (making it difficult to deal moderate damage at anything but close range).  Is the accuracy of that weapon affected by skills or tokens or anything else?

Comment: Badass rank accuracy might work for it, since certain affects seem to affect the mounted MG. For instance The Bee adds it's asinine amp damage to normal MG bullets (not saws/explosives though)

Answer (score 2):

**Using the 'scope' button while in the gunner seat will considerably increase accuracy.**

Comment: Unless your turret has a secondary attack like sawblade launcher does. And no, no other effects or skills.

Answer (score 0):

Badass Ranks invested into Gun Accuracy is the only thing that will affect it IIRC.

Comment: Does it indeed affect vehicles? Is it from your personal experience, or did you read it somewhere?